# Client IP address from webbrowser object

Tags: c#, .net, bho

Is there any way to get client IP address from webbrowser object in Browser Helper Objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A BHO is running on the client, so you can do something like this:

```
var host = Dns.GetHostName();
var ipAddresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host);
```

Mind you that it returns an array, since it's possible to have more than one IP address.